# Conditional insertion in YAML templates with variables at build time Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, multistage-pipeline

Is there a way to use varaiables defined in the pipeline(dashboard) to use conditional insertion on a YAML template for steps:

I mean i have this steps:

---

```
- ${{ if eq(variables.['somevar'], '')}}:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Var does not being declared
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
         echo "This is a step where the var 'somevar' does not being declared'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Another Step
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
         echo "This is another step where the var 'somevar' does not being declared'
```

This should run when the variable is not being declared

[image]

---

```
- ${{ if ne(variables.['somevar'], '')}}:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Var is being declared
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
         echo "This is a step where the var 'somevar' is being declared with some value'
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Another Step
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
         echo "This is another step where the var 'somevar' is being declared with some value'
```

This should run when the variable is declared

[image]

---

I know that it exist the Runtime parameters , but i don't want to use them every time that i run the pipeline (manually).I want that some pipelines run some steps,  when i have declared the variable, and some other pipelines don't run some steps when the variable is not being declared.

I also know that it exist the condition inside every step like

```
condition: eq(variables.somevar, 'value')
```

But i want to use conditional insertion to run in some cases, many steps like in the examples above. Not in just one step

Answer (score 4):

> I want that some pipelines run some steps, when i have declared the
> variable, and some other pipelines don't run some steps when the
> variable is not being declared.

Why not use the [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)? With the Runtime parameters used we can simply achieve your requirement.

Whatever, to achieve that by using the variables we can try to [Specify condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the Yaml templates:

Create Yaml templates :

```
# File: somevar-nondeclared.yml
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Var does not being declared
  inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
      echo "This is a step where the var 'somevar' does not being declared"
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Another Step
  inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
      echo "This is another step where the var 'somevar' does not being declared"
```

And

```
# File: somevar-declared.yml
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Var is being declared
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     echo "This is a step where the var 'somevar' is being declared with some value"
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Another Step
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     echo "This is another step where the var 'somevar' is being declared with some value"
```

And the `azure-pipelines.yml` for your reference :

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - template: somevar-nondeclared.yml 
  condition: eq(variables['somevar'], '')

- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - template: somevar-declared.yml
  condition: ne(variables['somevar'], '')
```

Thus, It will run windows job if you declared the variable when run pipeline. Otherwise it will run the Linux job in this example.

[image]

Comment: I think runtime parameters are used , when you just want to skip a job or a sequence of steps that are not working but you need to run the pipeline. Example a pipeline that have an Integraion a Migration Job and a Deploy Job , Sometimes you need to deliver as quick as possible the Deploy so manually you skipp the integration job with  Runtime parameters . But what about pipelines that you want to run with ci/cd where you simply don't have that job Integration but in other pipelines similar you have it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, you mean that we can only specify the parameters when run the pipeline manually, but for CI/CD, no way to specify them, right? However, according to your description, even with using the variable we still have to declare the variable manually. It's still not available for CI/CD. Please correct me if any misunderstanding.